# Nexus 5 IMEI number gone after updating to Lollipop

Tags: nexus-5, imei

My IMEI number has disappeared on my Nexus 5 and now I can neither call nor text.

Status of the phone says:

- Network:
  Unknown
- Mobile network type
  Unknown
- Service State:
  Out of service
- Mobile network state:
  Disconnected
- My phone number:
  Unknown
- IMEI:
  Unknown
- IMEI SV:
  Unknown

All of this happened after updating to Lollipop using bootloader.

I have tried several tutorial videos, such as:

- "How to Unroot Nexus 5 on Mac! - Restore to Complete Stock",
- "How to Upgrade, Downgrade, Restore ANY NEXUS Device on a Mac - Easiest Method"

Now is my Nexus downgraded to Android 4.4 and I can't text or call anyone. 
When I try to open the Camera I get the message "Unfortunately camera has stopped". The same thing happens with Google Play Store.

When I try to take a screenshot I get the message "Couldn't save screenshot. Storage may be in use." It's like it can't connect to the storage.

**Can I fix this? Is it possible to restore the IMEI without any backup?**

If not, should I lock the bootloader and send it to my carrier (I live in Sweden)?

**Note**: I have the IMEI number written down.

Comment: The IMEI number of the phone may be under the battery inside the phone.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to worry. Please follow the steps mentioned [in this Android Enthusiasts answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/90090/74590).

You just have to flash the images properly. Do a factory reset using the recovery mode.

- Volume Down + Power
- Bootloader screen will be visible
- Go to Recovery
- Power + Volume up key (few seconds) and then let go of the Volume up key, but keep pressing Power
- Select Wipe Dalvik cache
- Select Factory reset

Comment: Step 1 should be Volume Up + Volume Down + Power instead of Volume Down + Power