# Nexus 5 stuck on Google logo at boot

Tags: nexus-5, boot-loop

I recently unpacked, modified, and repacked the boot.img file and flashed it onto my Google Nexus 5.  When I rebooted the device, I was stuck at the Google logo screen.  I can access the recovery mode, but "wipe data/factory reset" did not fix the issue (still stuck on the Google logo screen).

I also attempted to sideload the stock image found here:

https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#hammerhead

Still no luck, as I was receiving "signature verification failure."  The device's bootloader is not unlocked. Anyone have ideas?  I am not concerned with losing personal data, I would be satisfied with just getting it back up and running.

Comment: How did you flash the modified boot image? Just repeat that process with the original one. I would think that should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I basically did an adb pull on the boot.img, unpacked it, modified it, repacked, it and then pushed it back to the device and overwrote the old one.  I don't have adb access anymore since I can't boot all the way, or else I'd just restore a working boot.img.  I used this guide: http://droidcore.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-edit-initrc-in-android.html

Comment: Well, I suppose the fallback option would be to unlock the bootloader so you can try to use the factory images. You'll lose your data in the process, but as long as you can get into the bootloader you should be able to do it.

Comment: Thanks I was able to use fastboot once I installed the proper drivers.  I am back up and running!

Comment: There is nothing to worry. You just have to flash the images properly. Please follow the steps mentioned in this [Android Enthusiasts answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89046/updating-from-version-4-4-to-version-5-let-me-to-a-dead-phone/90090#90090). The initial bootup usually takes time around 10 to 15 minutes. I'm up and running 5.0.1 without any problems.