# Nexus 5 stuck on “flying color dots lollipop” screen after Hard Factory Reset

Tags: nexus-5

I updated my Nexus 5 to Lollipop a month back and it was working fine. Suddenly one day my device didn't boot up so I did a factory reset and I got wipe/cache error and if I switch off the power and restart I get the flying color dots page and nothing comes up after that. I went to service center and they said it's a software issue and they can't do anything about it. How can I fix this?

Comment: The initial bootup for lollipop takes around 10 to 15 minutes. How long did you wait?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to worry. You just have to flash the images properly.

Please follow the steps mentioned in this [Android Enthusiasts answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89046/updating-from-version-4-4-to-version-5-let-me-to-a-dead-phone/90090#90090).

The initial bootup usually takes time around 10 to 15 minutes. I'm up and running 5.0.1 without any problems.