# Random crashes on Nexus 5 after installing (and uninstalling) Lollipop

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, crashes

I had been happily using a Nexus 5 for the past year until I did an OTA upgrade to Lollipop, after which it began crashing (powering off) multiple times per day without apparent pattern (sometimes during GPS navigation, during phone calls, while taking a picture, etc.)  In addition to requiring a reboot, these crashes sucked down battery.  I did a fresh factory install of Kitkat, which I expected to fix the problems, but they continued, even in safe mode.  Is there anything else to try, or is it time to buy a new phone?

**Update**: After posting, I installed the latest version of CyanogenMod, and my phone only crashed once, right after enabling location services for Twitter. Besides that, it worked fine, although it was not heavily used (on vacation) and battery life was poor (lasting only an hour or two). After getting back from vacation, I did the full wipe and factory install of Lollipop 5.0.1 suggested in comments. The phone crashed twice (sucking down battery) during the subsequent setup, although I made it through on the third try.

Comment: It occurred to me that I could try installing a third-party ROM.  I'm recharging my phone and will then try CyanogenMod.

Comment: Did you do a complete wipe? Wipe data partition, wipe cache partition and dalvik cache?

Comment: @VishnuPrasadKallummel I don't know if that was part of the process on the burn station I used; probably, they were.  Are the activities you described part of a factory reset? I've done that too.

Comment: Just check this answer http://android.stackexchange.com/a/90090/74590. Let me know if you have done these.

Comment: @VishnuPrasadKallummel Thanks for the advice. I did a total wipe with Lollipop 5.0.1. Phone crashed twice during setup. I'll update question.

Answer (score 0):

The Lollipop update was a red herring.  My phone was failing at the hardware level.  Unfortunately, the weeks I spent fiddling with it took me beyond the warranty period.